# is $_POST really safe?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, security, post

I have a table message in mysql

```
id(bigint)      sender(int)    receiver(int)     message(varchar)
1                 42                420           Hi
2                 80                32            Hello
3                 61                32            I love you
```

My delete.php code

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))mysql_query("Delete from message where id=".$_POST['id']."");
```

The page from where the user delete the message using ajax request

```
<div>sender:Romeo
receiver:Juliet
message:I love you</div>
<span id="3">delete</span>//delete message with id 3
<script>
$("span").click(function(){$.post("delete.php",{"id",$("span").attr("id")});
});</script>
```

Now as far as i know anyone can know to which page I am making this request and easily develop a fake form with method post and action delete.php and delete message.
Can anyone tell me how to prevent this?

Comment: Use an access token or something similar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: `$_POST` is not any safer than `$_GET` if that's what you mean

Comment: insert data using Parameters , not direct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to validate/authenticate the incoming data (i.e. is the current user authorised to delete the specified message?).  You also need to prevent SQL injection by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), rather than directly inserting user data into the query.

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) should be used for sanitizing user input for MySQL queries.

EG.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['id'] );
mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE id='$id'" );
```

Comment: As it says on the manual page you linked to, use of the `mysql_` functions is now discouraged in favour of PDO, etc.

Comment: truth said me to not use mysql_* function,so now iam in great confusion

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, but this was a MySQL question, not PDO_MySQL or MySQLi.

Comment: btw may anybody tell me what this function does

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Also, MySQLi and PDO_MySQL was essentially created to stop the bad coders. If you have good coding practice, it's not an issue.

Comment: +1, although I'd check `id` exists in the array before using it, since it will raise a PHP warning if you don't.

Comment: @BenPoulson: `mysql_` are going to be officially deprecated, so there's no reason to write new code using them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that event if you filter and escape the data, nothing prevents a user from learning the endpoint of the Ajax call and deleting all messages by guessing IDs.

Like Ed Daniel points out, you should be using authentication so that only authorized users can delete posts and only if they are the authors or otherwise have permissions to do so.

Comment: dude i stopped from deleting message from guessing and deleting

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix:

```
$id = array_key_exists('id', $_POST) ? (int) $_POST['id'] : null;
if ($id)
{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE id={$id}");
}
```

I've checked the item exists in the `$_POST` array first, to avoid PHP notices, and critically I've sanitised it with `(int)` before using it.

A couple of recommendations: always use braces in your `if` statements - it will save you a lot of trouble one day. Also, migrate to PDO or mysqli if you can, so you can use prepared statements. Lastly it's nice to have a case convention for SQL - you can write it in title case if you wish, but I tend to prefer upper for keywords, lower for entity names.

Comment: Is this safe from SQL injections? You arent escaping the post variable

Comment: This and combine it with some sort of session/cookie based user auth to make sure the user has access to delete this record in the first place. @Johan it's being cast to an `int`, anything other than a number will return `0` at worst. For strings et al you obviously need to escape properly.

Comment: @Johan - yes, I've forced it to be an integer; that is sufficient.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz - yes to authentication, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hope that Juliet had to log in to see the message in the first place! Basically, that's your answer - user authentication. If the submitter of the POST can't convince you that they're authorised to delete the message, then don't let them.

And as Olli Charlesworth points out, that SQL is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The page has to be accessible to the logged user only. You can simply check weather user is logged in by checking his user_id or anything similar in $_SESSION. Even one could post data from his m/c to your server, it would not be added because you've put the authentication check above. And you better to sanitize your inputs using prepare statement, mysql_escape or addSlashes, regexp etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example contains a big MySQL-injection issue.
No matter if you use values from $_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, $_FILES, $_SERVER which is controlled by the user (including USER_AGENT, filenames of uploaded files, etc...) you have to secure it.

The best way is, as suggested, using PDO (PHP Data Objects, an abstraction layer for database access).
`mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes any quotes like " and ', but doesn't help against every kind of injection.

In your case if someone uses `-1 OR 1=1` your whole table will be cleared. And `mysql_real_escape_string` can't provide any security.

Also you should implement some kind of an login, right now everyone is able to delete any records inside the table.

Check out the PHP manual for PDO: http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the logged users ID is equal to receivers ID.

if not, die